# Using awk to sum the values of a column, based on the values of another column and matching multiple other columns, append the sum and percentage

Tags: awk, sum, append, percentage

This is more or less a variant on [Using awk to sum the values of a column, based on the values of another column, append the sum and percentage to original data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654649/using-awk-to-sum-the-values-of-a-column-based-on-the-values-of-another-column/43655239#43655239) , but matching on two fields instead of one.

Input:

```
a;x;1
b;y;2
a;x;3
```

Desired result:

```
a;x;1;4;25.00
b;y;2;2;100.00
a;x;3;4;75.00
```

Hence, if the field in column 1 and 2 are equal, sum their column 3 and append the result. Also, append the percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `a[$1]` to `a[$1 OFS $2]` in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43655066/4162356):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR==FNR { s[$1 OFS $2]+=$3; next }
{ print $0,s[$1 OFS $2],$3/(s[$1 OFS $2]?s[$1 OFS $2]:1)*100 }
' file file
```

Untested, thou. Well, now tested.

Comment: Wow, amazing how fast and competent you respond. Works great, thanks!